# How to change System Navigation Bar color in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, uinavigationbar, navbar, statusbar

I want to change the colour of the system navigation bar but I can't.

I got this:

```
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart'
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

but it didn't work for me...

I used the code below to change the status bar colour it worked.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'
systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.white),
```

Answer (score 1):

In your MaterialApp, you should change the primaryColor:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.grey,),
  home: AppHome(),
),
```

Comment: What about custom colours that are not part of MaterialApp theme?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your parent widget

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: systemNavigationBarColor,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing color of a specific screen/widget, use SafeArea above Scaffold and wrap SafeArea with Container then try using color of that container.

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('Test Screen'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the change for app level the trying using this code in main function of the app :

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```